# Modify SqlDataSource at runtime to connect to another Sqlite file

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, runtime, sqldatasource

I have a connection defined for Sqlite in Web.Config. I have a SqlDataSource on a form that uses the above connection successfully to bind to a grid.

Now, I want to make this flexible so that I can connect the grid to any Sqlite data file in my App_data folder.

Assuming that the string variable fname contains the full path to an Sqlite file, here is the code I tried that executes on each Page_load (even post backs).

`SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = String.Format("data source = {0}", aFileName);`

Is this the correct way to do this so that SqlDataSource1 is then independent of the connection string coded in the web.config file? I'm asking because it seems to work the first time but later on selection changes in the grid, reverts to using the sqlite file specified in the web.config connection so if that is missing, it starts throwing "sql logic error -- table not found" sqlite exception on a popup message box.

Answer (score 0):

Got it after some experiments. The correct code will be:

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = String.Format("data source = {0}", aFileName);
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
   dataGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Reason: Since I'm setting the DataSource dynamically, I need to bind the data myself on each postback.

Comment: Update: While this is working in Local, it's not working in production. On a postback, it says can't open the file.